# JSOM Execute Query Synchronous

Tags: 2013, javascript, jsom

I have some JS methods that create site columns and add it to site content types. These are working fine if you use them once. But if I want to add a bunch of columns (within an array) it's not working:

**Failed: The object has been updated by another user since it was last fetched.**

Thats obvious, since I access the same content type object several times.

I also tried to use the callback of executeQueryAsync() and go recursivly through the array. But this doesn't work either. I got an Out-of-Memory-Exception.

Is there a way to execute the queries synchronously?

```
addFieldToContentType: function(fieldSTR, contentTypeSTR, successFUN) { 
    var clientContextOBJ = (csListBuilder.contextURL != "") ? new SP.ClientContext(csListBuilder.contextURL) : new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var webContextOBJ = clientContextOBJ.get_web(); 


    //get content types
    var contentTypesARY = clientContextOBJ.get_site().get_rootWeb().get_contentTypes(); 
    clientContextOBJ.load(contentTypesARY);

    clientContextOBJ.executeQueryAsync(function() {
        var numeratorOBJ = contentTypesARY.getEnumerator();
        var loopBLN = true;
        var contentTypeOBJ;

        //loop through all content types to get to our wanted one
        while (numeratorOBJ.moveNext() && loopBLN == true) {
            contentTypeOBJ = numeratorOBJ.get_current();
            loopBLN = (contentTypeOBJ.get_name() == contentTypeSTR) ? false : true;
        }   

        //Build the field Info and add it to the content type object
        var fieldOBJ = clientContextOBJ.get_site().get_rootWeb().get_fields().getByInternalNameOrTitle(fieldSTR);           
        var infoOBJ = new SP.FieldLinkCreationInformation();
        infoOBJ.set_field(fieldOBJ);

        contentTypeOBJ.get_fieldLinks().add(infoOBJ)        
        contentTypeOBJ.update();

        clientContextOBJ.executeQueryAsync(successFUN, function(senderOBJ, argsOBJ){
            if(csListBuilder.alertErrorsBLN) {
                alert('Failed: ' + argsOBJ.get_message());
            } else {
                console.log('Failed: ' + argsOBJ.get_message());
            }               
        });

    }, null);       
}
```

Recursive Approach:

```
function addSiteColumns(i) {
        //Recursive approach;
        console.log("Adding Column " + siteColumnsARY[i].nameSTR + " to Content Type " +  siteColumnsARY[i].contentTypeSTR);
        csListBuilder.addFieldToContentType(siteColumnsARY[i].nameSTR, siteColumnsARY[i].contentTypeSTR, function() {
            i++;                
            if (i < siteColumnsARY.length) {
                addSiteColumns(i);
            }               
        });                     
}
```

Comment: JSOM having only ExecuteQueryAsync method so we will need to do sync call for add multiple column at a same time.
You can create recursive function and use counter for call function itself in success of column add in content type.

Comment: As I said: I tried that and got of memory...

Comment: you will need to use JQuery deferred for this

Comment: Can you please post your solution with callback? Callback and recursion is one way to do that, I tend to think you did that incorrectly.

Comment: Its been awhile since I did JSOM.. first thought: Are you doing operations that require the JSOM context on the page to be re-initialized? Small test: Place the second update/create in your success function; once that works make it work with the array method you tried; because that is the way to go. If you get memory errors you are doing something wrong. Post the code you tried. extra note: Use the ``break;`` statement to quit your while loop, saves that loopBLN variable and is less error prone

Comment: @SergeiSergeev: I added the code... It seems to pe correct. But I think it's just too many elements in the array... If I reduce them it seems to be working fine...  Chrome seems to have less problems than Firefox. Maybe I have to splitt the items...

Comment: The recursive approach is the way to go. Your browser is throwing the out of memory error because you have a really weak machine or your code or/and the code on your current page is using too much memory. Here's some reference to solve this: 
https://auth0.com/blog/four-types-of-leaks-in-your-javascript-code-and-how-to-get-rid-of-them/
Also check for the local storage - if I remember correctly it also throws an out of memory exception when it is full.

Comment: You are running out of memory because you declare functions over and over again (as parameter for other functions) and each function gets a complete new scope with all data. This needs some major restructuring, start by taking out all Functions you pass as parameter and (by the looks of it) declare them on your ``csListBuilder`` object. Then you only pass a pointer as function-variable, not creating a whole new object.  Can't help much with example code.. I ditched JSOM for REST.. makes it much easier to work with Promises/Deferreds

Answer (score 1):

The pattern you need is something like this

**pseudo** code:

```
var myData = [1,2,3,4,5];

function addField() {
    if( myData.length>0 ){
        var addingThisOne = myData.pop();
        executeAsync( success );
    }
}

function success(){
    addField();
}
```

You could debate if it is recursion or not, key is that you do **not** pass a shitload of data around